# NASM: Validating input

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-64

I have a small assembly program where I am trying to read in an integer and validate that it is between [0-100,000]. This doesn't currently work. At the moment, a valid integer (e.g. 10) will cause the program to jump to the `invalidInput` label, and in turn the program exits.

I'm thinking that the cause of this error is due to the comparison prior to the jump. Is there a different way that integers which are entered by the user must be compared?

I'm thinking that the value which is read in has to be changed to an integer (converted from a "string"?)

This is one of my first ever assembly programs, so I'm still learning the basics.

```
section .bss
    value: resb 4
section .data

    prompt db 'Enter a integer between [0-100000]: ', 0xa
    promptLen equ $-prompt

    invalidMsg db 'Invalid data. Integers between [0-100000] are valid. Exiting.', 0xa
    invalidMsgLen equ $-invalidMsg

section .text 
global _start 
_start:

    ; Display prompt
    mov rdx, promptLen  ; message length 
    mov rcx, prompt     ; message to write 
    mov rbx, 1          ; file descriptor for stdout 
    mov rax, 4          ; system call for sys_write
    int 0x80            ; call kernel

    ;Read the value and store it
    mov rax, 3      ; sys_read
    mov rbx, 0      ; descriptor value for stdin
    mov rcx, value  ; where to store the input
    mov rdx, 5      ; 5 bytes 
    int 80h         ; call kernel 

    mov edx, value  ; move value to a register before comparing

    cmp edx, 100000 
    jg invalidInput ; jump if the input is greater than 100000

    cmp edx, 0
    jl invalidInput ; jump if the input is less than 0


    ; Other instructions (that aren't important for now) here


invalidInput:
    mov rdx, invalidMsgLen  ; message length
    mov rcx, invalidMsg     ; message to write
    mov rbx, 1              ; file descriptor for stdout
    mov rax, 4              ; system call for sys_write
    int 0x80                ; call kernel

    mov rax, 1    ; exit
    int 0x80
```

How can I validate this input?

Comment: What you're getting with `sys_read` is  string of characters. So, yeah, if you want to compare that to an integer you'll have to write a function that converts strings to integers. You should be able to find plenty of examples on how to do that here at StackOverflow and elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

The string you read must be converted to a binary value (you already said you thought it should be converted to an integer, well that is such a binary value), and only then you can compare it to another number. So find a conversion routine (many examples on the web, and on Stack Overflow).

Also, if, in NASM, you write

```
    mov edx,num
```

You are loading the **address** of `num` into `edx` and then compare that to `100000`. The address is almost certainly larger than `100000`. But you want the value stored there, so do:

```
    mov edx,[num]
```

and try again. This assumes that `num` is the address where the converted (binary) number is stored. As I said, comparing to a string is useless.